# Very long load times for the initial view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an intermittent problem where whatever view I set as my starting view, for my MVC3 project, in VS 2010, I get extremely long long load times.  I'm now looking at over 2 minutes without anything happening except the browser waiting.  I am working with a local DB on my dev machine, and the build time for the project is quick.  If I stop to debug in VS, none of my code is running.

When I stop debugging in VS, which takes very long as well, then I finally get a 404 in the browser.  What could be causing this, and what measures can I take to diagnose and resolve this issue?

I am using the VS built-in web server, not IIS, and VS 2010 Pro, so no IntelliTrace options.

**NEW:**  When I tried a machine restart, my machine seemed to hang up on the 'logging off' message.  I tried the restart because I experienced problems even accessing my C:\Development folder, also unexplained hanging.  After the restart, on trying to run the project again, I immediately got a compilation error.  That error was there from before the restart, and I suspect it had something to do with the total meltdown, but it's a simple misspelled property name in a view.

After fixing the compilation error, things are back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try [turning off IntelliTrace](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535799/debugging-mvc-is-very-very-slow)

Comment: It seems that's quite the culprit in other people's cases, but I am running VS 2010 Pro, and I don't have any IntelliTrace options,