# Problem closing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I suspect this is related to my [*Very long load times for the initial view in MVC3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809572/very-long-load-times-for-the-initial-view-in-mvc3) question yesterday, but I also think it counts as a separated issue.  I think other developers may experience this problem even without coding for MVC3 etc.  After experiencing yet another very long load time, I closed Visual Studio.

I now still have a running **devenv** process consuming 460MB of memory, and nothing I have tried will kill that process.  I have no visible applications open that might be holding onto it, and I can't kill it with Task Manager, nor with PowerShell's **kill** cmdlet.

I realise this question could be shoe-horned into a *SuperUser* question, but it is directly related to an anomoly with a development tool, and is very likely closely related to the development process.

Comment: Do you have any addons installed like Resharper?

Comment: It's definitely *not* a Server Fault question - it *could* be asked on Super User though.

Comment: Whenever I had such effects it was usually because some debugging session went haywire and/or I had installed some bad/very buggy component into the toolbox...

Comment: The only problem I have with VS2010 is, after updating to SP1 that is, is a crash-*after*-close that the SP1 patch was supposed to fix. Not a problem due to it crashing some 15-20 seconds after the program is closed but still annoying.

Comment: @Steve, I do have ReSharper installed, and some extensions, like Productivity Power Tools, but I have had these installed for months, and this problem is very recent, only since about Friday last week I think.

Answer (score 0):

According to this you can attach a new instance of visual studio to the hanging one and kill it there.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544459/cannot-kill-devenv-exe-until-logout

I just killed an instance that hang on "Loading Intellisense" forever and was unkillable by normal means.